# PropertyReferenceException: No property ids found for type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In the middle of a stack trace of my Spring app that uses JPA/Hibernate 4, I got the following message.

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ids found for type com.heavyweightsoftware.daybook.model.entity.calendar.Event

The error is on this line of a class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="UUID")
public Event event;
```

And here is the event class:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    public String   uuid;
    ....
}
```

This is my only many to one at the moment. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that ManyToOne relationships must be reciprocal. Setting up a OneToMany relationship with a List on Event appears to have fixed the issue.